# ng2Charts/chart.js changing chart type for one is impacting many charts

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a dashboard with multiple charts. Above each chart i have a select option for the chart type (bar, pie or line). Now...in my code it changes all of the charts on the site when you chose a type but i only want to change the chart where the user selected the type.

Here is a Stackblitz of my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvy8mf

Could you guys please help me?

```js
  shapes = [
    { id: "bar", display: "bar chart" },
    { id: "pie", display: "pie chart" },
    { id: "line", display: "line chart" },
  ];

onChange(event) {

    this.selectedType = event.target.value;
   
  }
```

```html
  <div id="content" class="form__card" *ngFor="let a of model[0]?.category; let ix = index">
   
      <ng-container *ngFor="let b of a.question; let iy = index">
       
                  <select *ngIf="categoryQuestion.questionType != 'text'" class="form-control input-sm " (change)="onChange($event)">
                    <option disabled selected>Wähle einen Chart Typ </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let t of shapes" [value]=t.id>{{t.display}}</option>
                  </select>

           

                <div *ngIf="selectedType === 'bar'" style="min-height: 200px;">

                  <canvas baseChart [data]="loadData(ix,iy)" [labels]="loadLabels(ix, iy)"                [options]="barChartOptions"
                    [legend]="barChartLegend" [options]="chartOption" [chartType]="'bar'"></canvas>

                </div>

                <div *ngIf="selectedType === 'pie'" style="min-height: 200px;">

                  <canvas baseChart [data]="loadData(ix,iy)" [labels]="loadLabels(ix, iy)"          [options]="pieChartOptions"
                    [chartType]="'pie'" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"></canvas>

                </div>

                <div *ngIf="selectedType === 'line'" style="min-height: 200px;">

                  <canvas baseChart [data]="loadData(ix,iy)" [labels]="loadLabels(ix, iy)" [options]="lineChartOptions"
                    [chartType]="'line'" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" [legend]="lineChartLegend"></canvas>

                </div>   
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Comment: stackblitz would be helpful, else too much work creating data. methods to replicate your case

Comment: Your are right so i made one. --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvy8mf I have a structure of 2 layers. There are multiple questions in multiple categories and i want to change the type on the chart where the user clicked the select. So far it works within a category for the questions but not if there are multiple categories ... then it changes the chart with the same id in each category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see [working code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxbuht)

The issue was because the selected value was stored at the level of category... however the choices were being made at the level of the question... this is why the first and third chart data was reading the same 'type' and second and fourth charts were reading the same 'type'

According to the hierarchy of data:

- category > question > unique-chart
- category (**previously** selected value was stored here)  > question > unique-chart
- category > question (**now** selected value is stored here) > unique-chart

[image: see this selectedType field added here, at the individual question level]

**onChange function**

```
onChange(event, ix, iy) {
    console.log("for:" + ix + " & " + iy + ", selected type" + event.target.value);
    this.selectedType[iy] = event.target.value;
    this.evaluationModel[0].category[ix].question[iy].selectedType = event.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you so much :)